# Nodejs query from URL not working

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a JS Array declared like this:

```
var phones = [
    {name: "Redmi Note 5" , manufacturer: "Redmi" , price: 9999},
    ...
];
```

I listen to this server with the following code:

```
app.listen(9999, function (err) {
    if (err) {
    throw err
    }
    console.log('Server started on port 9999');
})
```

This is the function I'm utilizing:

```
app.get('/get-items' , function(req , res) {
    var resu = phones;
    var man = (req.query['manufacturer'] === '');
    var mod = (req.query['name'] === '');
    console.log(man);
    console.log(mod);
    if (man)
        sortman(req , resu);
    if (mod)
        sortmod(req , resu);
    var jsonResult = JSON.stringify(resu);
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(jsonResult);
})
```

If I give a URL like `http://localhost:9999/get-items?manufacturer=Samsung` , I get both the log as false, and even if I don't give any parameter, both the logs still show false.

I would like to know whether I am indeed supposed to use `req.query['name']` or should I use something else?

EDIT: I have the required dependencies declared using require()

Comment: It'll return false because you are passing samsung and nothing(undefined). what is expected output?

Comment: Ok, but at least one of them must be true, right?

Comment: use `==` instead of `===`. what is expected output?

Comment: Same with `==` . When I give `http://localhost:9999/get-items?manufacturer=Samsung` it must be
`false
true`

And when I give `http://localhost:9999/get-items`, it should be
`true
true`

Comment: how it is possible, you are telling 'samsung' == '' ?

Comment: https://imgur.com/tt7JugU . This does not matter even if the query is there or not. PS. Even though the screenshot says req.param, I had implemented req.query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, If you pass any value to manufacturer or name. It'll check for an empty string and undefined.

```
app.get('/get-items', function (req, res) {
    var resu = phones;
    if (req.query.manufacturer) // ?manufacturer=Samsung
        sortman(req, resu);
    if (req.query.name)    // ?name=xyz
        sortmod(req, resu);
    var jsonResult = JSON.stringify(resu);
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(jsonResult);
})
```

Comment: And if I had a query like min-price, how would I write it here?

Comment: req.query[\`min-price\`]

Comment: @Sparker0i The problem was not that you were using ['data']. The problem was that you were also typing === ' '

Comment: Thanks, but even if I typed == it still wouldn't work

Answer (score 1):

That's because :

```
req.query['manufacturer'] is equal to 'Samsung' and 
req.query['name'] is equal to undefined.

undefined and '' (empty string) are two different things in javascript. And they are not equal.
```

If you want to check for all of these, use isEmpty() from lodash

```
var _ = require('lodash')
app.get('/get-items' , function(req , res) {
    var resu = phones;
    if (_.isEmpty(req.query['manufacturer']))
        sortman(req , resu);
    if (_.isEmpty(req.query['name']))
        sortmod(req , resu);
    var jsonResult = JSON.stringify(resu);
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(jsonResult);
})
```

isEmpty(val) will return true,  if val is any of these:
[empty Object, empty string, empty array, nil, undefined]

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to assign the manufacturer and the name to the variables `mod` and `man`.

```
app.get('/get-items' , function(req , res) {
    var resu = phones;
    var man = !!req.query['manufacturer'];
    var mod = !!req.query['name'];
    console.log(man);
    console.log(mod);
    if (man)
        sortman(req , resu);
    if (mod)
        sortmod(req , resu);
    var jsonResult = JSON.stringify(resu);
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(jsonResult);
})
```

Then when you call with `?manufacturer=Samsung`, you will have in your log `Samsung` and the sorting function will be called.

EDIT: You can coerce anything to boolean with the double exclamation mark `!!req.query['manufacturer']` will always return true / false, depending on if you have provided it.

You can read more about the operator here : [What is the !! (not not) operator in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)

Comment: No, I want to check whether they have any values in them or not. If there are no values, I want to assign false. I'm sorry I don't want to store the values as such